# add another query to add to a page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am suck on some code here. It displays an article as a result of clicking on a link from another page displaying title and content etc.

My issue is I need a different record set to appear on the page as well what is here.

In this case it would be a list of all the other titles which have the same ‘artcampaign’ number as the article loaded. Kind of like a related articles or full list within this category. Any help appreciated with this.

```
$sql = "
SELECT articles.id AS articleid, articles.art_title AS title, articles.art_url AS art_url, articles.art_content AS content, campaigns.id, campaigns.camp_title AS camptitle, campaigns.camp_name AS campname, campaigns.camp_url AS camp_url
FROM articles
LEFT JOIN campaigns ON articles.art_campaign = campaigns.id
WHERE art_url = ?";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['art_url']); // assuming it's a string?
    $results = $stmt->execute();

        echo "
        <h2>{$campname}</h2>
        <H3>{$camptitle}</H3>
        <H4>{$title}</H4>
        ";
?>
        <div class='right-section'>
        <h5><?php echo "{$campname}"; ?> Links</h5>
        <ul calss='section-list'>
            <li>dummy text</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <?php echo "{$content}"; ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: so write another query underneath and display the results in the same sort of way (using echo etc). Which bit are you stuck with? The SQL logic, or the way to output it, or what?

Comment: Side note don't do this `..\"" .$_GET['art_url'] . "\"` that is an invitation to SQL injection.

Comment: I have never had to do two queries on a page before. The logic part I am lost. I would have to identify what the current 'artcampaign' number is (easy enough) but then output a list of all of them which are the same as the current one. That bit I am completely lost where to begin.
I am still a novice to this :S hope that answer helps

Comment: well, if you know how to get the campaign ID into a variable, then underneath your existing code (or wherever in the flow you want it to be) write another SQL query which includes the campaign ID, execute the results, and display them the same as you're doing already. Essentially it's a copy of what you've got now, but with a different SQL query.

Comment: Note: I have improved the code slightly so it is now secure as mentioned above.

So the other query I'm looking to also include is a full list of all articles to go in the 'section-list' div class (in improved code). It would determine what articles by the campaign ID. I'm guessing it would need a 
if($results->num_rows) {
 While($row = $results->fetch_object())  ??